# Upgrading laptop HDD to SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, upgrade, toshiba-laptop

I have a 2014 toshiba laptop that has a 750GB HDD in it. I want to upgrade it to an SSD.

The laptop initially had Windows 7 on it, wich was later upgraded to Windows 10 when microsoft offered it for free.

So first, considering the laptop is mostly used for internet browsing(no gaming) and basic software(MS office, vlc and such), would a 240GB SSD be enough for Windows 10?

And second, I want to do a fresh install of Windows 10 on the SSD, so I created a recovery USB drive using the Windows recovery drive creator. Is that all I need? What about the Windows 10 serial key? Is it saved in that recovery drive I created? Do I need the wipe the old drive first before installing Windows 10 using the recevory drive on the SSD?

Thank you

Comment: If you have less than 200 GB used right now, it will be enough.

Comment: @gronostaj I have not even 100gb free on the actual hard drive, but theres a lot of unused programs, files, games etc..

Comment: Well, we can't tell you how much you're actually using. You need that much + say 20% for overprovisioning (spare space to improve SSD performance and reliability) + some extra space because you'll be storing more data over time.

Comment: Its possible that your windows 10 PC is activated with a "Digital License" ...check in system information.

Answer (score 2):

You should have no issues with installing Windows 10 in terms of space.  However, you are going to be using a significant percentage of the drive right after install.

To start off, your 240 GB SSD is probably over-provisioned and you likely only have around 220 GB of usable space before creating a volume and formatting.

Based on the Windows 10 version and installation options, it will require between 25 and 40 GB.  Additionally, 35 GB of space is reserved space for updates.   Based on the amount of RAM you have and you dont change the default settings (which I dont recommend, unless you know what you are doing), even more space will be used for the page file and hibernate file (if hibernation is enabled).

Depending on all of this, over 1/4 to over 1/3 of the drive will be used for Windows.  That being said, you still have plenty of space left, if you dont need lots of storage.

As for installing Windows, the recovery drive is not used for installing Windows, its for recovering a non-booting machine.  You need to create the install media using using the [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO).  This will create a bootable USB to install Windows.  You can then manage the licese from your Microsoft account.  You can move the license from your old machine to the new one.

Comment: _"You can move the license from your old machine to the new one."_ - I don't think that's correct. It's an OEM license (unless Windows was bought separately) and those are bound to a machine they were installed on.

Comment: @gronostaj If Im not mistaken, Win 7 and 8 OEM licences are no longer OEM bound when upgrading to Windows 10 through the free upgrade process.

Comment: Are you sure the recovery drive cannot be used to reinstall Windows ? Cause it clearly says on this page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026852/windows-create-a-recovery-drive "you'll be able to use the recovery drive to reinstall Windows 10. "

Comment: Also, the laptop has 6GB of RAM for information purpose

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install a new copy of Windows 10 and provide a Windows 7 license key. Make sure you have the correct edition (Home, Pro, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 was already running, so the license is in the Microsoft Licencing Server. You made a recovery USB already, so that will suffice to reinstall Windows 10. I have done this a number of times.

A 256 GB SSD is likely bare minimum. We use that size when clients have all their documents on a server.

Since you only have 100 GB remaining on a 750 GB drive, I suggest you consider a 500 GB drive as your minimum size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you sure I dont need to wipe the old drive? Because if I reinstall Windows 10 on the SSD using the same serial key, what happens to the serial key on the old drive? I could just connect the drive to another machine and it would have an active Windows 10 on it using the same key? How is that managed? I dont know if you get what I mean

Comment: You do not need to wipe the old drive. I have an old (working) hard drive in the basement. So long as both SSD and HD are not operating at the same time, there is no need to wipe it. The same key (licensed as per my post) will work.  You can install the old drive in another machine to get data, but just do not operate it as a working system.